# TIme zone problem - JSF f:convertDateTime with local date time

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, timezone, localdatetime

I have Simple bean with property

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

In the web page I want to see current time in the different time zone

```
<h:outputText value="#{testBean.localDateTime}">
                            <f:convertDateTime timeZone="Europe/Warsaw"
                                               pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" 
                                               type="localDateTime"  />
```

</h:outputText>

Unfortunately time does not show given time zone date/time. Problem coming from primefaces date time picker or calendar which is working with Java 8 local date time.

I want to save user entered date in UTC , but show in user time zone time.

Comment: Are you using `p:datePicker` with the `timeZone` attribute?  https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/datepicker

Comment: Yes, timeZone does not work with local date time, see in the API (This attribute is only relevant for java.util.Date in combination with the built-in converter.)

Comment: Then you probably need a converter on `p:datePicker` as well.